# ANTLR function as argument

Tags: java, antlr, antlr4

I'm creating a language with ANTLR4. I'm trying to make possible to pass function as method's parameter. But I'm unable to find ane resources. Maybe someone could give a hint or resources if there are any available?

My end goal:

```
public int function1()
{
  int a = function2(function3(1));
}

public int function2(int i)
{
  return i + 1;
}

public int function3(int i)
{
  return i+1;
}
```

Comment: You're not passing a function as a parameter here, you're passing the results of executing a function. If parameters are expressions, and function calls are an expression, essentially every C-style language grammar supports this and could be used as a reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A function call would simply be an alternative in your expression rule:

```
expression
 : expression ( '+' | '-' ) expression
 | INTEGER
 | IDENTIFIER
 | functionCall
 ;

functionCall
 : IDENTIFIER '(' arguments? ')'
 ;

arguments
 : expression ( ',' expression )*
 ;
```